# Huge amount of gas being used for small computation

Tags: solidity, gas, web3j

I have just added one other part to my contracts addUser method (setting the isPermitted field) and it has blown up the amount of gas it uses to the point I keep getting out of gas exceptions. The code of my contract that corresponds to this is

```
contract UserStorage{
  struct location{
      bytes8 latitude;
      bytes8 longitude;
      bool checked;
  }

  struct userData{
      bool isPermitted;
      bytes ownData;
      mapping (address => bytes) friends;
      address[] friendsList;
      mapping (bytes10 => location) locations;
  }

  mapping (address => userData) private users;

  function addUser(bytes ipfs, bool permitted){
      users[msg.sender].ownData = ipfs;
      users[msg.sender].isPermitted = permitted;
  }
}
```

I am calling this using a web3j wrapper in android with

```
userStorage.addUser(new DynamicBytes(ipfsHash), new Byte(true)).get();
```

It is storing ipfs data to the users account. It's using on average 5 million gas for that one operation, reporting as bad instruction on etherscan. Any idea why it's so high and what I can do to lower the gas usage? Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide the transaction hash or a link to Etherscan from when you tried this?

Comment: I'm not clear - are you getting out-of-gas error, or are you getting invalid opcode/bad instruction? You say both, but they are different. I'm guessing it is invalid opcode. This means something went wrong and your code threw an error somewhere. It this case it will use up all the gas you supplied (that's what currently happens for all exceptions). So don't focus on the gas, look for an error somewhere. Your code here looks ok. The line you added in `addUser` should increase gas use by about 20k only.

Comment: @EdmundEdgar This is the link to etherscan https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0x16b97f408b3d5fd764f9111364917df1fccca75fc52aca12349d431f7e7c2108, I assumed it was an out of gas exception but I think I assumed wrong, why would this throw an error then?

Comment: @benjaminion Have you any idea what the invalid opcode would be? It seems to compile fine with solc and doesn't have any errors, do you think it could be with how the web3j wrapper is accessing the contract, as I said before it was just updating the ipfs, without the permitted bool.

Comment: "do you think it could be with how the web3j wrapper is accessing the contract" -> yes, I do suspect this. I don't know  web3j, though, so I can't really help on that. Your contract itself looks ok and I executed it in Remix just fine.